# Where are the resource files physically located in Spring Roo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I'm testing out Spring Roo and everything is working fine. But I can't seem to find where the resource files like dojo.js, Spring.js, tundra.css etc are physically located.

Even when creating a WAR file using 'perform package', the resource files are not inside the WAR file.

But when deploying the app to Tomcat and trying to access something like server/myproject/resources/dojo/dojo.js, I can see and view the JS file itself.

What actually is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I used Roo, they were borrowed from Spring Webflow and contained in the jar `spring-js-resources-x.y`.

My Spring-MVC configuration file `webmvc-config.xml` contains this line:

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

It says that `resources/*` will be looked for in the filesystem first and in the classpath later.

You can extract those files to the web directory if you need to modify them.